# How to separate script editor from document (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I'm writing some script for my Documents, Spreadsheets and Gmail. I would like to know if there is a way to save all my script to separate files in a specific google drive folder. I don't like having to go to the backend of my Documents and Spreadsheets in order to edit my script.

Would I have to call the document from my script using "getByID" or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you create a new document in Drive you can select *Script*. If you don't see the script option, try going [here](http://www.google.com/script/start/).

You will, however, need to call your document using `getByID`. There my be other complexities if you are using `onEdit` type triggers.

A lot more information can be found under the **Types of Scripts** heading at [Google Apps Scripts Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

You could go *advanced* and pull your script in behind the Document as a Library and then using the script behind the Doc to make the calls to the library, but that's a bigger discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm curious about that bigger discussion. Would you be able to give me a link so as to look into that thing about: "pull your script in behind the Document as a Library"?

Comment: You can find out more about using Libraries in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries). In short, you load the other project as a resource. You name the library, eg `MyLib` then any function not ended with _ will be available to you. ie `MyPublicFunction` will be available but `MyPri ateFunction_` will not. Libraries are a very useful way to create wrappers for RESTApi services, common `ScriptDB` instances etc.